# Magento 2 homepage product sort by position not working

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2 (ver. 2.3.6) i have two different products section on homepage,

1. Featured Products
2. New Products

for both sections i have create 2 categories
like:

1. featured products
2. New Products

**Note :- alredy set category display settings:

- Available Product Listing Sort By: Position
- Default Product Listing Sort By: Position

for homepage products call i had follow below steps:

- Go to Magento admin panel
- Content -> Pages -> home page
- Click the Insert Widget button
- Then choose Catalog Product List
- Choose condition as category and its ID**

Now my question is:
When I open both categories I can see all products according to given position from admin, but on homepage position not working any idea? or any other way?

Thanks in Advance !!!